# Regular Expression in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I need to test that the URL contains this string

form.aspx?title=domestic_forms&id=4783&dataid=508866

How do I do this with reg expressions. I need to set up a goal.

Many thanks

Comment: Is it that precise string, or any string that contains those querystring arguments with any values?

Comment: If you want an EXACT match, check the "url contains" option for your goal and enter in that exact string. There's no need for regex. regex is for when you want to match a patten. Like for instance, if you have a=X and X can be any number.  If you want it to ONLY match a=1 then you don't need regex. But if you want to match if a equals any number, that is where regex comes into play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this: ?

```
form\.aspx\?title=[a-z_]+&id=[0-9]+&dataid=[0-9]+
```

This matches any URL that looks like

```
form.aspx?title=<any word with characters a-z or _>
&id=<any number>&dataid=<any number>
```

Comment: Not quite sure what this would match. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer. What exactly do you want to match? Do you just want to match, or do you want to extract something from it?

Comment: I would like to match the exact URL above in my first post and not "any word with characters" etc as in the example you posted. I have change my Goal funnel to form2.aspx\?title=domestic_forms&id=4783&dataid=524261 with a backslash in front of the ? to escape it. It brings back pages from the Top Content section when filtering so hopefully that works. Any more advice much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, not sure how goals in google analytics work, but if you want to match exact strings you just have to escape special characters like '?' or '.'. So 'form2\.aspx\?title=domestic_forms&id=4783&dataid=524261' should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression match on a static string is not recommended. Just use the "head match" for the goal and input that string.